# android: RelativeLayout margin/padding issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my listView like this:
[image]

But my result is this:
[image]

and heres my xml for the list item [listview uses inflator]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" 
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_new_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/num"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:contentDescription="delete"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do i remove those spaces around the colored textView? i tried putting padding=0dp etc etc but nothing worked.

heres the xml for the listview

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Comment: try negative margin. like -5dp

Comment: Use ImageView instead of TextView

Comment: where you want to remove spaces, between number and text?

Comment: i want to remove the white spaces around the colored textbox. it should stick to the boundaries of the listview item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for something like this:

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/testlist"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#58f"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_new_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/num"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="some text that you want after it"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
             android:contentDescription="delete"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
             android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: trying this.is this relative layout?

Comment: im looking for exactly the same as in the pic u posted but can u please post the entire xml

Comment: i have added the listview used and the relative layout which makes out the elements in the listview just check it again and mark it as answered if you are satisfied with the outcome

Comment: the answer below this also worked. cant i mark both of them ?

Answer (score 0):

See if your ListView have padding also just for a clean code use match_parent and not fill_parent...